# Partial form is being rendered in the console but does not appear in the browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to render a form in `js.erb` file when the condition is true.
Following is my **create.js.erb** file

```
<% if condition is true %>       
    $('#status-message').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'form') %>")
<%else%>
    #do something else
<%end%>
```

The `create` method in the controller is:

**controller**

```
def create
    #code
    respond_to do |format|
     format.js # render app/views/phone_numbers/create.js.erb
    end
end
```

Now when I checked in the console it is rendering the `form`

```
Rendered phone_numbers/_form.html.erb (4.2ms)
  Rendered phone_numbers/create.js.erb (8.8ms)
```

Adding **_form.html.erb** as requested

```
<%= puts "Hello world"%>
<h3><%= Equipment.last.title %> </h3>
<h3><%= Equipment.last.price %> </h3>
```

But its not appearing on the browser. What am I missing ?

Comment: You may try adding debugger in the `form` and check if its been rendered or not

Comment: may be some conditions are not allowing to render the view

Comment: I replaced the line of form rendering with simple `<%= puts "hello"%>` this is getting displayed in the console.

Comment: try putting it inside the form

Comment: also can you paste the contents of form

Comment: I tried that. That's also getting displayed. `Rendering phone_numbers/create.js.erb
Hello world
  Rendered phone_numbers/_form.html.erb (4.5ms)
  Rendered phone_numbers/create.js.erb (8.3ms)
`

Comment: Added `_form` @DeepakMahakale

Comment: Do you have `Equipment.last` this present in db

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143479/discussion-between-user3576036-and-deepak-mahakale).

Comment: since you are seeing puts, verify `title` and `price` is not null/empty string.

Comment: No they are not null. `Equipment.last.title` => `Lathe` so is `price`. The problem is it stuck in the previous `create` action and not moving forward.

Comment: I am not even getting a empty `form`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved this in chat - the problem was that the `#status-message` element was inside a `#status-box` element that was hidden via css (with `display: none;`), so the fix was simply to add `$('#status-box').show()` to `create.js.erb`.